# Send simulated mouse/keyboard events in windows without programming

Tags: windows, events, simulation

I have an windows app and I want to send click event on it's window.

for example in android and using ADB.exe I use this code:

`adb.exe shell input x,y`

Comment: You might be looking for AHK = AutoHotKey. Btw. i would be surprised if there were .exe files running on Android.

Comment: @TheUser1024 AHK is writing a script. which I think counts as programming, and is probably as diffiult/easy as batch files, which can be harder than a regular programming language.. 'cos programming languages have compilers that give very precise error messages. i'm not sure that AHK does

Comment: You can with nircmd but I am not sure how

Comment: `C:\nircmd>nircmd.exe sendkeypress a` <-- that sends an 'a' to the current window, where it was written but as of writing i'm not sure how to get it to go to another window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question heavily depends on how the term "programming" is defined.

In any case, you can simulate mouse input in Windows using various utilities available for download online, or alternatively using PowerShell. Both of these approaches could count as programming.

It should be fairly obvious that the only way of simulating mouse input without using anything that counts as programming would be using a mouse.